# Combine data of two async requests to answer both requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to bring together two async data sources (each of them arrive at my server via a POST request and have a common, otherwise unique ID). To answer any of the two POST requests, I need the data supplied by both POST requests. What data structure, library etc. can I use to let each of the POST handlers wait for the others value?

#### Edit:

To illustrate my problem with code: I have two functions, let's call them `back` and `front`, that are called at arbitrary times:

```
var synchronizer = //what I'm looking for

function front(req) {
  var id = req.data.id
  var frontValue = req.data.value;
  synchronizer.supplyFrontValue(id, frontValue).then(function(backValue){
    req.send("The product is " + (frontValue*backValue));
  });
  // or alternatively, instead of a promise, use a callback:
  // synchronizer.supplyFrontValue(id, frontValue, function(backValue){
  //   req.send("The product is " + (frontValue*backValue));
  // });
}

function back(req) {
  var id = req.data.id
  var backValue = req.data.value;
  synchronizer.supplyBackValue(id, backValue).then(function(frontValue){
    req.send("The quotient is " + (frontValue/backValue));
  });
}
```

Comment: Asynchronous? Promises!

Answer (score 1):

You could use promises for that. Native promises are supported in every newer browsers (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises), for others you could use a fallback library.

Example:

```
var request1 = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    doAjaxRequest("someurl", function(payload) {
        resolve(payload);
    });
});

var request2 = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    doAjaxRequest("someotherurl", function(payload) {
        resolve(payload);
    });
});

Promise.all([request1, request2]).then(function(payloads) {
    console.log("All my payload", payloads);
});
```

Comment: Uh, sorry, I'm on the other side, in the node.js server.

Comment: Promises work on both sides and should be supported by newer versions of Node.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not issuing two post requests, but *answering* them. So I do not have the common scope where both promises live to combine the promises like you can in the last 3 lines of your code

Comment: Since you separated your code into two functions, you'll probably need to call them when needed, e.g. `front()` calls `back()` and the other way around... They could return the promise so you could write `front().then()` or `back().then()`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101989/discussion-between-perseids-and-kraftwer1).

Answer (score 0):

```
var synchronizer = {
    data:{},
    frontValue:function(id,value,cb){
        var data = this.data;
        if(data[id]){
            data[id].front = value;
            if(data[id].hasOwnProperty('back')){
                //in case we have multiple calls of frontValue
                //make sure we have one back value in data

                data[id].cb(data[id].front,data[id].back);
                cb(data[id].front,data[id].back);
                delete data[id];
            }
        }else{
            data[id] = {
                front:value,
                cb: cb
            }
        }

    },
    backValue:function(id,value,cb){
        var data = this.data;
        if(data[id]){
            data[id].back = value;
            if(data[id].hasOwnProperty('front')){
                //in case we have multiple calls of backValue
                //make sure we have one front value in data

                data[id].cb(data[id].front,data[id].back);
                cb(data[id].front,data[id].back);
                delete data[id];    
            }

        }else{
            data[id] = {
                back:value,
                cb: cb
            }
        }

    }
}

synchronizer.frontValue(1,'front',function(f,b){console.log('from front front=%s back=%s',f,b)})
synchronizer.backValue(1,'back',function(f,b){console.log('from back front=%s back=%s',f,b)})
```

I have made the assumption that id is an alphanumeric and it can be a property of an object. This code uses callbacks and it could be edited to use Deffered promises. Although as stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Deferred) deffered is obsolete, but i couldn't find an easy way to make it using the new promise api.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:
You can set some reasonable timeout (TTL)
The client is sending the POSTs asynchronously

On receipt of the post you can register the Id in a database. The db element would just need the id, data1 and data2.
Then after registering the id and the appropriate data you'd call a setTimout in your handler that checks the db element for both data1 and data2.
When you eventually get both POSTs or the TTL passes the function in the setTimeout invokes the response callback and each POST returns.